# Got 404 error on https://example.com/blog/

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

`_config.yml`:

```
baseurl: "/blog"
url: "https://example.com"
```

This works perfectly on http://localhost:4000/blog/ but got a 404 error when published on github-pages.

```
https://example.com/assets/main.css      => ok
https://example.com/blog/assets/main.css => 404
```

Here is my repo: https://github.com/arzyu/blog

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

`arzyu.github.io/blog` is now resolving to your custom domain `arzx.org`.

You no longer need to set baseurl, and your config must be :

```
baseurl: ""
url: "https://arzx.org"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I want to serve my blog at https://arzx.org/blog/. Do I need to do other settings